# HTML geolocation service force accept alltime

Tags: javascript, html

For our webapp we use the HTML 5 location service like this:

```
  // does the service work n this browser
  if(navigator.geolocation) {

    // get position
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {   

    // there is something wrong
    }, function(error) {

    },{timeout:maptimer});

  // location service does not work on this browser
  }else{


  }
```

My (Firefox) browser asks me to accept this feature. Firefox gives me two choices:

- Accept always
- Accept only this time

But on some devices the browser does not give any choice. If the user selects "Accept only this time" and they move to the next page, the browser will prompt again.

Is there a way to force (in my code) the location service to only prompt the option "Accept always"?

Comment: No. That is against the browser's security model. Only the user can set that in the browser options.

Comment: No, you can't force the user to Accept always, is a question about security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Permissions UI are only controlled by browser vendors, and [the API](http://natalieorbach.com/mystreets/) does not specify a way to override them.

By the way, on Firefox 24 the default button I see is 'Share Location', and it has a dropdown with 'Always Share Location', 'Never Share Location' and 'Not Now'. I see why you would want to ask for Always Share by default, but this can't be done, for the sake of protecting users' privacy.